# Gparted Not letting me Resize Partition and Add more Disk Space

Tags: partition, gparted

Forgive me, as I am not the best at describing tech problems.

I have a /dev/sda5 ext4 partition running Linux Mint, and a /dev/sda7 running Kali Linux, both of which are in an extended partition.. I want to add space to my Mint, as Kali Linux does not demand much space. I took off 50 Gigs from my Kali Linux. However, Gparted does not give me the option to add THAT free space to my Linux Mint. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

Kali Linux is on /dev/sda6. /dev/sda7 is swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... you have something else in `/dev/sda6`?  "Recent" versions of gparted are able to move partitions.  Your problem would be:

- move `/dev/sda6` down (to use up the space freed in `/dev/sda5`)
- move `/dev/sda7` down (to put the free space on its end)
- extend `/dev/sda7`

The partitions have to be unmounted, according to the [documentation](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-move-partition):

> ***Moving a Partition***
>
> Moving and resizing a partition can be performed by a single gparted operation.
>
> To move a partition:
>
> 1. Select an unmounted partition. See the section called “Selecting a Partition”.
> 2. Choose: Partition → Resize/Move. The application displays the Resize/Move /path-to-partition dialog.
> 3. Adjust the location of the partition. See the section called “Specifying Partition Size and Location”.
> 4. Specify the alignment of the partition. See the section called “Specifying Partition Alignment”.
> 5. Click Resize/Move. The application displays the resize/move partition operation in the Pending Operations pane.
>
> ***Tip***
>
> If the partition is an operating system boot partition, then the operating system might not boot after the move operation is applied.
>
> If the operating system fails to boot, see the section called [“Fixing Operating System Boot Problems”](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-operating-system-boot-problems).

Comment: Apologies, but my Kali Linux is /dev/sda6. /dev/sda7 is Swap. Let me edit that. Though I do not think that makes a difference.

Comment: Does your version of Gparted provide the ability to move a partition?  That would be on the Kali Linux, of course.

Comment: Yes, it does. This is my idea, but I have no experience, so please tell me if it will work. I intend to move the free space to precede my Kali Linux on /dev/sda6 rather than come after it, and then I should be able to resize my Linux Mint on /dev/sda5?

Comment: That sounds right: adjacent partitions are (?) always adjacent numbers.  You probably have to make the system in the moved partition boot again (as hinted in documentation), and then resize the filesystem using that partition.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I just tried that and it didn't work. I am going to boot into a full live session of Gparted and experiment around without saving changes to disk until I get it. I'll post back here if I'm still unsuccessful

Comment: Ok so I decided to go by vertical position of the partitions in the GUI rather than by the more logical method of number. It worked. I moved /dev/sda6 to the left (my Kali), then /dev/sda7 to the left (my swap), then finally moved /dev/sda5, which is my Mint, to the left and added space. I had two warnings and I couldn't find out what they were, but so far, so good. I just would really like to understand how hard disks work, as it would make this a lot easier to understand and do correctly.